# Getting an error while subtracting variables

Tags: bash, if-statement, arithmetic-expressions

I am writing a bash script and i get an error when i try to subtracts 2 variables. I tried many ways of declaring the subtraction as a single variable, but i am constantly getting errors. What's the right way to declare the variable? Thanks in advance.

```
if [ ${$packets1 - $packets2} -gt 30 ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a working solution for Bash :

```
packets1=300
packets2=176

if [ $(( packets1 - packets2 )) -gt 30 ]
then
    echo "This is true!"
fi
```

Regards!

Comment: sorry. I left spaces around the variables declaration. I should not have done that. @melpomene I have corrected that.